# Aardvark: Plugging in headphones forces selection screen. How to automate?

Tags: headphones, 17.10

I've installed Ubuntu Aardvark (Beta2) on my Dell Latitude 5480 and I have not found a single thing that wasn't auto-detected. However there is 1 auto-detect that really bugs me:

If I plug in my headphones, a audio selection box pops up allowing me te select 'Headphones', 'Headset' or 'Microphone'. Basically a proper question but it annoys the sh*t out of me since it captures all the keyboard input. (Even if the screen is locked, so it keeps me from entering my password to unlock)

Is there a way to get rid of this Audio Selection screen? And, preferably, make it default to 'Headphones'? And is this a Gnome3, Aardvark or PulseAudio issue?

Comment: +1 because the question is well formulated and I think the problem persists in the released version. But: Have you in the meantime updated to the released version? Pre- release versions are off-topic here.

Comment: I ran `do-release-upgrade` and `apt dist-upgrade` and no new versions/packages are found. Is there some other thing I can do to get my beta2 to the final release?

Comment: I don't think so. You probably are on the released version now.

Comment: I've installed the Cinnamon desktop environment and this 'problem' has disappeared. Therefore I can deduct that it is a Gnome3 issue. Don't have  a solution for it though :(